# Unable to understand this gcd property: $\gcd(a,b) = \gcd(a, a+bk)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I studied that
$$\gcd(a,b) = \gcd(a, a+bk)$$
where $k$ belongs to an integer.

Now suppose $a = 8$, $b = 15$, and $k = 4$.
So, $\gcd(8,15) = 1$, but $\gcd(8, 8+15(4)) = 4$,
which doesn't satisfy this property.

Comment: you can easily prove JJ Hoo's statement by taking $gcd(a,b)=p\Rightarrow a=px_1, b=px_2$ where $gcd(x_1,x_2)=1$  and $p,x_1,x_2 \in \Bbb{Z}$

Comment: There is a typo in the statement - see the linked dupe for the correct statement and proofs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that you have found a counterexample is because the property you stated is incorrect. I believe you mean the following property instead, for $k\in\mathbb{Z}$:
$$gcd(a,b)=gcd(a,b+ak)$$
A proof follows from definitions you have likely learned, and I encourage you to attempt such a proof to ensure that you understand why this must be true!